# How do i remove date from a date and time from an excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have a very huge sheet with date and time values. I am exporting the calendar start date and end date into excel from outlook. I just want the time value in the field. Upon searching i found an formula {=INT()} but its showing error.
[Attaching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGm2w.png) the snapshot of the sheet for your reference. Thank you.

[Edit 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNk1R.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your date-time value (actually are date-time values and not text looking like dates) would sit in A1 for example:

```
=A1-INT(A1)
```

And format your result to time. Also, when you don't need to do any calculations with these values, you could also just format the cells to only show the time.

---

In case your values are text values looking like date-time values try:

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,5,LEN(A1)))
```

That would give you a number you can custom format as time

Comment: Error.  I have edited my answer and added a snapshot with your formula.

Comment: Yes i do not have calculations for these date and time values.

Comment: I can't see your edited answer with a snapshot of the error. Are you sure they not textvalues that look like dates?

Comment: How to format the cells to only show the time?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-numbers-as-dates-or-times-418bd3fe-0577-47c8-8caa-b4d30c528309). However you haven't answered if you sure these values are not just text that look like dates.

Comment: Those cell values are left-aligned so unless the OP has manually changed the cell alignment, those values are text.

Comment: @Jeeped, I guess it is, so just added an option for that. Was waiting for some confirmation from OP.

Comment: @JvdV, yes the cell values were text and the second function worked as a charm. Thank you all for your help.